# How to insert image with transparent background, in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `.png` pictures with a transparent background.
I would like to add them to my page, at the moment I use

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="foo.png">
</div>
```

but when I open the page (through chrome) the background color is white, and I don't want it white, I want it to be transparent.

I would like not to use CSS, but if there is no other option so I'll do it.

Comment: Are you sure the image just isn't showing the page background through it...

Comment: I don't think so it will be possible without CSS. You can add the following code in your css if you want, it will do the job ` .thumbnail,.foo { background-color: transparent}`

Comment: I think you are using bootstrap, and `.img-thumbnail` have default `background: #fff`

Comment: I am using bootstrap.
Is it possible through the bootstrap class to make the background transperent

Answer (score 4):

Please note that, if you are not giving any colours for the background, then by default it will be white on most browsers! If you are using chrome, you can do like this:

```css
body {
  background: url("transparent1.png") transparent,
              url("transparent2.png") transparent;
}
```

As said in the comment by [KittMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3461955/kittmedia), if you are targetting new browsers, replace `transparent` with:

```css
body {
  background: url("transparent1.png") rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
              url("transparent2.png") rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This way, you can overlay two images and keep them transparent too. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: `transparent` is deprecated and should be replaced with `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` if you don't need to support older browsers.

Comment: yeah, it didnt work, both of the options (transperent and rgba)